# Need professional help! Error on running npm run dev

Tags: nuxt.js

yangziyi@Yangde-MacBook-Pro ~/Documents/KOOCO/bbos (master)
$ npm run dev

> bbos@1.0.0 dev /Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos
>   cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server

[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos/server/**/*
[nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
/Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28
  return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
          ^

TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor
    at createFSEventsInstance (/Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28:11)
    at setFSEventsListener (/Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:82:16)
    at FSWatcher.FsEventsHandler._watchWithFsEvents (/Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:252:16)
    at FSWatcher. (/Users/yangziyi/Documents/KOOCO/bbos/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:386:25)
    at LOOP (fs.js:1566:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bbos@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bbos@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/yangziyi/.npm/_logs/2019-07-17T08_07_09_569Z-debug.log

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're unlikely to get a response this way. 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I resolved this problem on my own. I tried reinstalled Nuxt.js again and rejected install jest, and run "npm run dev" again. It worked. Can't figure out why...